# ACCESS reports doesn't open. Workaround is Layout view

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a Access version from yesterday, where everythink works. Today I made a copy of if and changed a label in the report. After saving the report I am not able to open the report agian. I tried to open the report in the navigation, there is a short loadtime and then nothing happens. Also when I use a copy from yesterday and I just save the report without changes, the report doesn't work. When I open the Backup from yesterday without any changes, than I can open the report normaly. The report is based on a temp table which work great for itself. When I create a copy of the working report, than this copy works until I save changes. Than it broken too. I also did some restarts of the pc and nothing changed... I got crazy, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Access can have weird corruption issues sometimes. Try a compact and repair on a copy of your original, working version. Just because it currently works doesn't mean data corruption has not already occurred. If you are lucky the repair will work. If not you will have to recreate your report; mostly by copy/paste but test often so you don't copy whatever corrupt element is there.

Comment: I alredy compact and repair the database, there are no changes. I tryd a bit. What is more weird is the fact that when I open the form in the layout view and change it to preview, than the report shows up. I try to replicate this behavour with VBA, but Access just hang up. For this reason I create the report new and hopefully it doesn't break that fast again...

Comment: Thanks @SunKnight0 After trying to delete more and more of the existing report, I give up to repair the current form, because it help not a bit. Than I just created a new blank form, provide the table as source, setup the group filter and copy and paste all fields of the old report at once. After clicking the button, everythink works as it should be. I am very happy to solve this bug. It seams that the report has an issue with itself... Next time if Access doesn't work I know how to react.

Answer (score 0):

Access can have weird corruption issues sometimes. Try a compact and repair on a copy of your original, working version. Just because it currently works doesn't mean data corruption has not already occurred. If you are lucky the repair will work. If not you will have to recreate your report; mostly by copy/paste but test often so you don't copy whatever corrupt element is there.